# How Can I Execute *nix or BASH SOURCE CODE in Azure Functions?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I have already written Azure Functions in Python, and know there's also official support for other popular dialects - JS, Java, .NET, etc. BUT, I have a special scenario, where I wish to execute some functions originally written in bash, or to be able to access such *nix utilities as calc, sed, awk and more.

I know that Azure Functions are meant to abstract away the server and even environment(?), but is there a way one can still install and run *nix like utilities or for that matter any exes (since *nix can port).

Some ideas am toying with:

- include binaries in /bin folder of my python project,
- and then invoke it using something like:

  ```
  from subprocess import call

  call(["cal", "-y"])
  ```

Problem; Can I do this without having to deploy my own binaries?

**TL;DR**: How to execute own binaries and access Shell inside Azure Functions?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, Azure function is running on `Windows Server`.

After my research, I found that the azure server was pre-loaded with git bash.

You can find the following path on the Kudu:

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\Git
```

If you want to run *nix  command `calc` on windows, you need to download [calc for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/calc.htm) execution files and upload it to Kudu.

[image]

[image]

Then add the current directory to the environment variable.

```
D:\home\site\mybin>set PATH=D:\home\site\mybin;%PATH%
```

[image]

Please make sure you add your environment variable in front of the variable `D: \Windows\System32;`  so that you can overwrite Windows own `calc` command.

**Verify:**

[image]

When you execute `calc` commands in Python, please use the `os.environ` and `os.putenv` to set your own environment variables.